# Idea for collections of available hours with minutes and deleting busy hours

Tags: java

i want to make list of available hours with minutes when client can have a visit. For example i have list of available hours with minutes from 08:00 to 16:00 and client now client can choose which hour he want and he choose for example 10:00 and his visit time is 0:30 so next available time is from 08:00 to 10:00 and from 10:30 to 16:00 now its easy when i have one visit but when will be more visits and available time will be for exmaple from 12:30 to 13:20. How storage available hours ? I have idea with Map<String, List> where key is hour and value is list of minutes and just delete hours taken when visit will be assigned to client.  I can delete visit start and visit end time but how delete time between visit start and end? Maybe someone implemented something like this and have other idea.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date visitStartTime = sdf.parse("12:30");
    Date visitEndTime = sdf.parse("13:30");
    Date newVisitStartTime = sdf.parse("13:00");
    Date newVisitEndTime = sdf.parse("13:30");

    Map<String, List<String>> mapHoursAndMinutes = new HashMap<>();
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("8", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("9", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("10", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("11", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("12", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("13", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("14", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("15", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));
    mapHoursAndMinutes.put("16", List.of("10", "20", "30", "40", "50"));

    for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : mapHoursAndMinutes.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey().equals(visitStartTime.toString().substring(0,2))){

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the smallest amount of time is 10 minutes, and that this is not some decentralized/asynchronous application.

Start off by creating a datatype called `Timeslot` that represents 10 minutes. Give it a String holding the meetingId. Please note - this meetingId ***MUST BE UNIQUE***. If it is not, your entire application falls apart. Plus, it would be a bad id if it cannot uniquely identify a meeting - that is the entire point of an id.

Then, in another class, have an array/List of `Timeslot`, representing each of the possible 10 minutes segments throughout the day. So for example, if you work from 10AM-2PM, you would have an `array.length` of 24 --> there are 6 10 minute slots in an hour, and 10-2 is 4 hours, so 24.

Then, in that same class, create 2 methods - 1 to `add` a meeting to your array/list of timeslots, and another to remove.

`add` - your method will need 3 parameters to hold the meetingId, the startTime, and the endTime. I would avoid using Date for these, something simple like a string will work, or maybe an int. Then, figure out which `Timeslot`'s in your array/list fall under the timerange that they selected. After that, do a check to make sure that ***ALL*** of the specified `Timeslot` are available. You can do this by checking each of the specified `Timeslot` to see if their meetingId is null. If so, then just set the meeting id to the parameter meetingId for those timeslots. If not, then maybe return false, or throw an exception. Point is, you cannot have 2 meetings at the same time, right?

`remove` - this works similarly, but your only parameter should be the meetingId. Have it loop through the array/list of `Timeslot`, then check each meetingId to see if it matches your parameter meetingId. If so, set the `Timeslot` meetingId to null, then continue through the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Mainly you could organize meetings into predefined slots and have a flag for available.
Further depends on requirements you can link additional entities on a slot (person, etc) and group per days.

A trivial implementation can be:

```
public class TestSpots {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map<String,Spot> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("spot_1", new Spot(10,30,11,0));
        map.put("spot_2", new Spot(11,0,11,30));
        System.out.println("spot_2 "+map.get("spot_2"));
        map.get("spot_2").occupied = true;
        map.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+" "+v));
    }

    static class Spot
    {
        int StartH, StratM, EndH, EndM;
        boolean occupied=false;
        public Spot(int StartH, int StratM, int EndH,int EndM)
        {
            this.StartH=StartH;
            this.StratM=StratM;
            this.EndH=EndH;
            this.EndM=EndM;
        }
        
        public String toString()
        {
            return StartH+":"+StratM+"-"+EndH+":"+EndM+", status="+ 
                   ((occupied==true) ? "occupied": "available");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
spot_2 11:0-11:30, status=available
spot_2 11:0-11:30, status=occupied
spot_1 10:30-11:0, status=available
```